# Linearly Independent Vectors--Story Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose we have a club with exactly $5$ students. Show, using vectors, that we cannot form $6$ groups so that every two groups share exactly $1$ student.

So if we let $v_1 , \dots ,v_6$ be $6$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^5$, where the $j$'th entry of $v_i$ is $1$ iff student $j$ is in group $i$ and is $0$ otherwise, then we can consider $c_1 v_1+\dots + c_6 v_6=0$ and show that each $c_i=0$. To do this, expanding $(c_1 v_1+\dots + c_6 v_6) \cdot (c_1 v_1+\dots + c_6 v_6)=0$ gives:

$c_1 |v_1|^2+\dots +c_6|v_6|^2+2(c_1c_2 + c_1c_3+\dots +c_5c_6)=0$ since $v_i\cdot v_j=1$ when $i \neq j$.

I cannot figure out how to proceed from here to show each $c_i=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Basically $\mathbb{R}^5$ can be spanned with 5 independent bases. So, it is impossible to have 6 linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^5$, because one of them can be expressed as a linear combination of other 5 vectors.

Comment: but how does one arrive at the desired contradiction given the equation present?